# Services rospy.wait_for_service using ROS melodic

Tags: ros

I'm learning about ROS, now I'm doing some examples using a Server and Client, there's something that I don't understand specifically is when ros blocks a service, I mean

```
rospy.wait_for_service("add_two_ints")
```

according to the documentation it blocks until the service named add_two_ints is available.
but then is necessary to create a handle for calling the service

```
add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
```

my question is rospy.wait_for_service() will execute n times? until the service finish its work?
thanks so much I'm so confused about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So
`rospy.wait_for_service("add_two_ints")`
checks if the service is available and blocks as long as it cannot reach the service.
And

```
add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
```

creates the object which communicates with the Server.

If the server is available during the call of `rospy.wait_for_service()`, the function returns and it is not checked further. If the server fails during execution of the remote function the try catch block has to catch the error.